# Spring data right outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have For Entities Like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="documentTermValue")
public class DocumentTermValue extends ModelBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="taxonomyTermId")
   private TaxonomyTerm term;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="documentId")
    private Document document;

    @Column(insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Long documentId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="document")
public class Document extends ModelBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="document")
    private List<DocumentTermValue> termValues = new ArrayList<DocumentTermValue>();

}
@Entity
@Table(name="taxonomyTerm")
public class TaxonomyTerm extends ModelBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="taxonomyId")
    private Taxonomy taxonomy;

    @Column(insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Long taxonomyId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="term")
    private List<DocumentTermValue> termValues = new  ArrayList<DocumentTermValue>();

}
@Entity
@Table(name="taxonomy")
public class Taxonomy extends ModelBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="taxonomy", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TaxonomyTerm> terms = new ArrayList<TaxonomyTerm>();
}
```

I need to select (subset of DocumentTermValues ) right join TaxonomyTerm 
like this SQL statement

```
select * from (select * from document_term_value as dtv where   dtv.document_id=10) as B right join taxonomy_term as tt on B.taxonomy_term_id = tt.id where tt.taxonomy_id=1;
```

How can I do it with spring data JPA ?
do I need to right native SQL query to perform this select?

Comment: You mean with JPA, since Spring Data JPA is nothing other than a wrapper around the JPA API. JPQL does NOT support RIGHT OUTER JOIN, as the JPA spec would tell you

Comment: Yes I mean with JPA. Thanks very much